# Api Call With Nested Map Flutter

Tags: json, rest, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a POST call to my server that requires my data to be shaped like this:
[image]

```
{
    "dispensary": 1,
    "order_detail": [
        {"product_size": 1,
        "quantity": 1}
    ]
}
```

But when I make my api call, I get a 500 error on my back end saying the data looks like this:

```
{'{"dispensary":1,"order_detail":{"product_size":1,"quantity":1}}': ['']}
```

I am making the call like this:

```
   Future getdata(dispensary, order) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = prefs.getString('token');

  var url = '$server/api/customer/order/getdata/?access_token=$token';

  Map<String, dynamic> orderRating = {
    'dispensary': dispensary,
    'order_detail': order
  };

  await http.post(url, body: orderRating, headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }).then((http.Response response) {
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case (200):
        var responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        Rate rateData =
            Rate.fromJson((responseData[1]['rate_response']['rates']));

        print('uploaded successfully');
        print(rateData.carrierId);

        break;

      case (400):
        print('Bad Data');

        break;
      case (500):
        print('Failed Upload');
        isUploaded = false;

        break;
      default:
        print('Unable to get rates');
    }
  });

  print('uploaded successfully');
}
```

With order_detail being a map itself of {"product_size": 1,
"quantity": 1}.

I cannot complete the call to my server. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Hi there,  I think there is a bug in the server. Try to send data without encoding

Comment: I have with no success

Comment: Can you provide url + token to test on my side

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what are you doing, because it's not the whole future function in it ... but I can make a guess you're trying to make a post request, where the body have some dynamic data.
What are you doing right now as far as I can see is that you're putting a map inside a map which is not what you want.

My suggestion is something like this:

```
Future<http.Response> postSomething(int dispensary, List<Map<String,dynamic>> order) async {
  final String url = 'yoururl';
  final Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'dispensary': dispensary,
    'order_detail': order
  };
  final request = await http.post(url: url, body: convert.jsonEncode(body));
  if(request.statusCode == 200) {
    return something
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to send the request!!!')
  }
}
```

Hope that my answer will help you and give a clearer idea. :)

Comment: I'ved tried the List<Map<String,dynamic>> method with not success. I've updated my code for more clarity

Comment: Dart has specific syntaxes, so you should use more specific functions, like giving the future a type and the parameters in your function a type also, in order to be more specific with your code and know what the function should return. Hope you'll understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `toJson` methods to your objects. call `toJson` when generating your requests `body`

`body: orderRating.toJson`
should return the json structure as seen in this snippet

```
{
    "dispensary": 1,
    "order_detail": [
        {"product_size": 1,
        "quantity": 1}
    ]
}
```

```
class OrderRating{
  int dispensary;
  List<OrderDetail> orderDetail;

  OrderRating({this.dispensary, this.orderDetail});

  OrderRating.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    dispensary = json['dispensary'];
    if (json['order_detail'] != null) {
      orderDetail = new List<OrderDetail>();
      json['order_detail'].forEach((v) {
        orderDetail.add(new OrderDetail.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['dispensary'] = this.dispensary;
    if (this.orderDetail != null) {
      data['order_detail'] = this.orderDetail.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class OrderDetail {
  int productSize;
  int quantity;

  OrderDetail({this.productSize, this.quantity});

  OrderDetail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    productSize = json['product_size'];
    quantity = json['quantity'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['product_size'] = this.productSize;
    data['quantity'] = this.quantity;
    return data;
  }
}
```

The above code was generated using a tool found [Here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)